# Elasticsearch: In the type-ahead search, how to stop receiving 'text' in the response?

Tags: security, elasticsearch, response, typeahead

We are using typeahead search in Elasticsearch. Security scan found a vulnerability i.e. when we send request as:

```
{
  "namesuggest": {
    "text": "<!DOCTYPE xxe [<!ENTITY testrxxe SYSTEM \"file:///testfile\">]>",
    "completion": {
      "field": "suggest"
    }
  }
}
```

We get below response:

```
{
"_shards":{
"total": 2,
"successful": 2,
"failed": 0
},
"namesuggest":[
{
"text": "<!DOCTYPE xxe [<!ENTITY testrxxe SYSTEM \"file:///testfile\">]>",
"offset": 0,
"length": 62,
"options":[]
}
]
}
```

'text' is returning the injected value. How to get rid of 'text' in the response? We don't want 'text' in the response from Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) to do it, Example:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "exclude": [ "text" ]
    },
    "query" : {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The typeahead doesn't return '_source', so I don't think source filtering can be applied here.